# How to move ms display from LHS to RHS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

The little bubble that shows the ms taken to display the page. How can I configure it to display in the RH corner instead of the LH corner.

Have tried access setting via global.asax.

Was able to trial it by changing the source from

```
<div class="profiler-results left"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="profiler-results right"></div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set the profiler popup position like so:

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.PopupRenderPosition = RenderPosition.Right;
```

You only need to set this once, so Global.asax.cs' `protected void Application_Start()` is a good place.